# Seams to Sewing

Tags: add-on, seams

I need assistance with exporting a sewing pattern from a 3D model in Blender. I've used the 'Seams to Sewing pattern' add-on, which exports an SVG file with markers. However, these markers are color-matching ticks, making it challenging to work with many panels. Is there a way to export a UV map with numbered labels or recommend an alternative add-on or script for this task?

Here is what seams to sewing pattern exports as a SVG.

[image: seams to sewing pattern]

Here is what I'd like to accomplish.

[image: numbered seam example]

Comment: I don't know, but a possibility is to ask the addon's developer ;)

Comment: Another user, Misslin Quentin, has added the numbers that you are looking for. The original author of the add-on seems to be not so active lately because the merge request for the changes is still pending. But you can download the updated version here: https://gitlab.com/qmisslin/blender-seams-to-sewing-pattern/-/archive/master/blender-seams-to-sewing-pattern-master.zip  - project site is: https://gitlab.com/qmisslin/blender-seams-to-sewing-pattern

Comment: [2] make sure the UV islands have a margin for the numbers. They are added on the outside.